# Integrate is giving finite result for divergent integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 10.2.0 or earlier and fixed by 11.0.**

---

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, a}]
```

returns

```
ConditionalExpression[-ExpIntegralEi[-a c] + ExpIntegralEi[a c], Re[a] > 0 && Im[a] == 0]
```

but the integral does not actually converge for any values of c or a (because near x = 0, Exp[c x] ~ 1, so the integrand has a 1/x singularity).  If I replace either c or a with an actual number, then Mathematica correctly says that the integral does not converge - even if I replace c with a positive real number, satisfying the returned condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug, and Mathematica is incorrectly evaluating the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral despite the default PrincipalValue -> False (and continues to do so even if you manually specify this).

Answer (score 6):

**Expanded in response to comment by OP**

The result in the question also is obtained with Mathematica "10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)".

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, a}]
(* ConditionalExpression[-ExpIntegralEi[-a c] + ExpIntegralEi[a c], 
   Re[a] > 0 && Im[a] == 0] *)
```

which can be simplified for `a > 0 && c > 0`.

```
FullSimplify[s1, a > 0 && c > 0]
(* 2 SinhIntegral[a c] *)
```

(The same result is obtained for `a > 0 && c < 0` but not for `a > 0 && c == 0`.)  This is the Cauchy Principal Value result.

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* 2 SinhIntegral[a c] *)
```

which seems strange, because `PrincipalValue -> False` is the default.  Thus,

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && c > 0]
```

returns unevaluated with the expected error message

```
Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(c x)/x does not converge on {-a,a}. >>
```

Giving `a` and `c` specific real values likewise produces this error message, as noted by the OP's comment.  Perhaps, `Integrate` becomes confused, when no constraints are placed on the parameters `a` and `c`.

Comment: The Cauchy principal value is a very specific method for dealing with divergent integrands, and I do not think it is standard to assume it is being used when not specified.  And more to the point, why does Mathematica assume it should only use the CPV when c and a are left as variables, but not for specific numerical values?

Comment: I assumed the setting for `PrincipalValue` was `Automatic`, but you're right, it's `False`.  I guess a user-setting for `PrincipalValue` makes `Integrate` choose an approach that does not try to avoid the singularity.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Setting `PrincipalValue -> False` does not change the result cited in the question.  Perhaps, this might be described as a bug.  By the way, +1 for your answer.

Comment: Of course.  Somehow I confused myself.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since `PrincipalValue`is by default set it to `False` (thanks, @bbgodfrey), it helps to indicate that `a` is a positive real number:

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The way to look at `Integrate` is that it tries to find a generic integral over a ***complex*** line.  Sometimes you have to give it extra information to get it to think right.  Sometimes even when you do, it still has trouble analyzing the complex-number situation.

Compare with this complex line integral that goes around zero:

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, I, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
(*
ConditionalExpression[
 -ExpIntegralEi[-a c] + ExpIntegralEi[a c],
 (c == 0 || Im[c] <= 0 || Re[c] <= 0 || a Im[c] + Re[c] <= 0) &&
  (Re[c] >= 0 || c == 0 || Im[c] <= 0 || a Im[c] <= Re[c])]
*)
```

*Note: This integral is off by `Pi I`, so this falls into the doesn't-quite-get-it-right category.*

---

A more direct way to get divergence, assuming you know where the singularity is:

```
Integrate[Exp[c x]/x, {x, -a, 0, a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]